# Adding more parameters to a Discord Bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have written a basic Discord Bot for my D&D group. It allows us to roll the dice using commands and sends results instead of using an honor system where we say what we roll. However, it has two major drawbacks:

1: You can only roll one die at a time, and

2: You cannot add any modifiers.

I have seen many Discord Bots, especially ones that search Youtube for music, that can have multiple parameters when running a command, such as "!play *songname*". How would I make it so my bot can have multiple parameters, such as !roll (dice type, amount, modifiers) instead of just !roll_d20?

Code is as follows:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands # used to create bot commands

import random # adding this fixed a problem, don't delete
from random import randint # generates random numbers for dice rolls

import sys # used to safely shut down the bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') # creates an instance of a bot
    
@bot.event # says when the bot should be ready as a message in the IDE
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready to roll!")

@bot.command() # allows users to test the response of the bot from Discord
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Ready to roll!'.format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # rolls a d4 and shows the result
async def roll_d4(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,4)
    await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d4 and got a ' + str(x) + '!').format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # rolls a d6 and shows the result
async def roll_d6(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d6 got a ' + str(x) + '!').format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # rolls a d8 and shows the result
async def roll_d8(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,8)
    await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d8 got a ' + str(x) + '!').format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # rolls a d10 and shows the result
async def roll_d10(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d10 got a ' + str(x) + '!').format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # rolls a d12 and shows the result
async def roll_d12(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,12)
    await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d12 got a ' + str(x) + '!').format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # rolls a d20 and shows the result
async def roll_d20(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,20)
    if x == 1:
        await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d20 and got a Nat 1!').format(ctx.author))
    elif x == 20:
        await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d20 and got a Nat 20!').format(ctx.author))
    else:
        await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d20 and got a ' + str(x) + '!').format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # rolls a d100 and shows the result
async def roll_d100(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    await ctx.send((str(ctx.author) + ', you rolled a d100 got a ' + str(x) + '!').format(ctx.author))

@bot.command() # shuts down the bot
async def stop(ctx):
    await ctx.send(("Logging out. See you next session!").format(ctx.author))
    sys.exit()

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: I see that this question has been answered, however I just want to put this out there for some ideas in regards to having an advantage or disadvantage roll or skill rolls. The code could be improved a fair bit, however, the logic still applies. See _rollskill & roll functions.

See [here](https://github.com/Skelmis/DnD-Discord-Bot) for the full bot. [Here](https://github.com/Skelmis/DnD-Discord-Bot/blob/master/bot.py#L230) for the roll command and [here](https://github.com/Skelmis/DnD-Discord-Bot/blob/master/bot.py#L353) for the roll skills command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily combine all of the commands into one as follows, i don't know D&D so i didn't get what you meant by modifiers.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dice(ctx, dice_type: int, amount: int):
    results = []
    for role in range(amount):
        x = random.randint(1, dice_type)
        results.append(x)

    await ctx.send(f'You have rolled {dice_type} for {amount} times and got {results}')
```

[image]

Comment: modifiers in dnd get added to rolls, for instance if you had a strength modifier of +2 and were lifting a stone, you would roll a d20 and add 2 to the result

Comment: So the dice would be 22? or the result +2?

Comment: result plus two, so if the dice came up as 13, you would have 15 total. don't worry, I got it figured out, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do string manipulation to take the user message just as /roll 'number of dices'd'how many dice faces' + 'modifiers', I did a single command on my Discord Bot to roll any amount of any kind of dices and add modifiers.

What I did was take the user message, split by spaces, put therms with 'd' in it in a dices list, put any other therm in a bonus list, and finally pick a random number betwen 1 and the amount of dice faces per each type of dice.

[image]

[image: This one shows every result for each type of dice]
Here goes the github link that contains the dice cog for my own Discord Bot

https://github.com/Voz-bonita/Discord-Bot/blob/master/Dices%20extension.py